# Xamarin AVD Storage Issue

Tags: xamarin, emulation, simulator

I have created an Android Virtual Device, with this specification below, Using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017.

```
Device: Nexus 6
Target: Android 8.0.0 - API Level 26
CPU/ABI: Google API Intel Atom (x86)
Skin: HVGA
RAM: 768
Internal Storage: 200
SD Card Size: Blank
Use Host GPU
```

I’m getting this error message.
Unexpected install output: Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space

Any Ideas?

Comment: `Internal Storage: 200`... Increase your internal storage back to the *default* of 800MB to allow enough room for everything to install property

Comment: I tried increasing the internal storage to 800, however, when I tried starting the AVD, it failed.

Answer (score 4):

Just restart your android emulator using the emulator's interface (click and hold the power button, then select restart).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Restart Emulator It will work.